# Get the value from select input on a form with typescript Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a form html code write with angular 6 typescript and i don't know how to get the selected value from the component?

below is my html page.

```
<article>
    <h1>What is your gender?</h1>
    <h2><span>Select a gender:</span></h2>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
        <option value="3">Intersex</option>
        <option value="4">Trans</option>
        <option value="5">Others</option>
    </select>
    <p><span>You selected: </span><b>{{selectedDay}}</b></p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reactive form and create a formGroup but just to make it simple you can use `formControl`.

*components*

```
  selectControl:FormControl = new FormControl()
```

*template*

```
<article>
    <h1>What is your gender?</h1>
    <h2><span>Select a gender:</span></h2>
    <select [formControl]="selectControl">
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
        <option value="3">Intersex</option>
        <option value="4">Trans</option>
        <option value="5">Others</option>
    </select>
    <p><span>You selected: </span><b>{{selectControl.value}}</b></p>
    <button (click)="selectControl.setValue('4')">Set Value</button>
</article>
```

> this may look alternative to `ngModel` but I just promote reactive forms

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-control-example)

Answer (score 2):

In .ts file just create a variable like:

```
public selectedDay:string;
```

Add this in select tag:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedDay">
```

As you are you using two way data binding the value will be updated to the variable,once you select the value from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

try this, in your Component.ts file, write as follows:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'src/home/home.html',
  styleUrls:  ['src/home/home.css']
})

export class HomeComponent {
  selectedDay: string = '';

  //event handler for the select element's change event
  selectChangeHandler (event: any) {
    //update the ui
    this.selectedDay = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

and in your .html file, try this:

```
<article>
    <h1>What is your gender?</h1>
    <h2><span>Select a gender:</span></h2>
    <select (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
       <option value="1">Male</option>
       <option value="2">Female</option>
       <option value="3">Intersex</option>
       <option value="4">Trans</option>
       <option value="5">Others</option>
    </select>
    <p><span>You selected: </span><b>{{selectedDay}}</b></p>
</article>
```

Comment: No need to add **selectchangeHandler**, because angular binds to that variable automatically. If you are going to process anything further on dropdown change then you can add that handler.

Comment: yes, you can use binding but what if in select tag you have an *ngIf e.g.             <select class="form-control select1" id="Acquirer" name="Acquirer" (change)="updateMerchantAcquirer($event)">
                                <option *ngFor="let acquirer of acquirerList; let i = index" value={{i}}>{{acquirer.businessName}}</option>
</select>

Comment: now you success get the value but what about set the value to the form or clear the form ?? my recommendation use angular forms solutions like template or reactive forms